# Get WP_Query query after execution?

Tags: wp-query, query, wp-parse-args

It it possible to get the configuration of a the latest called WP_Query? I need to use it for debugging.

For example, if i run something like:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
...
```

Could i get the $args array later by doing something like `$the_query->args();` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [the `$query_vars` property](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$query_arguments = $the_query->query_vars;
```

Which should return an associative array of query variables. To test:

```
var_dump( $query_arguments );
```